# Where can I find up-to-date flutter courses?

Tags: flutter

i'm really tired of old flutter courses etc.
There saying 'We are up to dated or 2021 updated' but all of them is old. Specially in null safety and some syntax, implementations.

Where can i find a good and up-to-date course, book, tutorial etc. for new programmers?

Comment: I would say follow flutter.dev official page. also, Flutter yt channel keep posting good things. My favorite is widget of the week.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks, i'm already looking for some things that i make wrong. But i need a books, course etc. starting zero on flutter. I'm really new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you are really new, don't have to study NullSafety yet, just change the version of your flutter SDK, then use an older version and study with the free material present on Youtube.

To change your Flutter version just have to checkout on the root folder of Flutter or use a FVM like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6vKde1vIGQ&ab_channel=FlutterExplained